# Register new device on apple developer for titanium appcelerator project

Tags: ios, certificate, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

I already have running app actually for development with 3 devices registered on apple developer portal, i need to register another one, so i ask myself if i need also to download certificate and provisioning profile and re-install it on my mac ? 
Another question :i use pushwoosh as push notification platform, i have to re-configure also then?

Thank you

Comment: This is not really an Titanium Specific question but more a general iOS issue. So I removed the Titanium related tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to install on a 4th test device you will need to add that 4th device to the provisioning profile. That updated profile you will need to download and install on your local machine and with that new profile you can install it on the 4th device.

There is no need to update any certificate, they're not related to devices.

Comment: Thank you Rene for your response